# Swift - converting an array to struct

Tags: swift

I have an array with a list of data as following `Data = [City, ZipCode, gpsLat, gpsLong]`

I am trying to convert in struct  as follows

```
struct Location  {
    var zipCode: Double
    var nameCity: String
    var gpsLat: DOuble
    var gpsLong: Double
}
```

I am using the `for-in` loop

```
var resultat :[Location] =  [] 
for item in Data {
    resultat.append(Location(zipCode: Data[item][0], City : Data[item][1],  gpsLat : Data[item][2], gpsLong : Data[item][3]))
}
```

I got the message

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Int'
```

Comment: change Data[item] to Item. for loop is giving you the item from the Data array

Comment: Note that in Swift, types and classes should be capitalized, but method names and variable names should not. So if you have an array of "stuff" it should be named `data`, not `Data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Achu says, you should use `item[0]`, not `Data[item][0]

A `for ... in` loop defines a new local variable that contains each element in your array.

So if you have an array:

```
let array = ["now", "is", "the", "time"]
```

Normally you would loop through the array like this:

```
for item in array {
    print(item)
}
```

That is the recommended way to do it.

If you wanted to loop through the indexes, that code would look like this:

```
for index in array.indices {
    let item = array[index]
    print(item)
}
```

or this:

```
for index in 0..<array.count {
    let item = array[index]
    print(item)
}
```

Note that a third option would be to use the Array object's `enumerated()` method:

```
for (index, item) in array.enumerated() {
    print("item at index \(index) = '\(item)'")
}
```

That would output

```
item at index 0 = 'now'
item at index 1 = 'is'
item at index 2 = 'the'
item at index 3 = 'time'
```

You could also write that loop as a forEach:

```
array.enumerated().forEach() { (index, item) in
    print("item at index \(index) = '\(item)'")
}
```

All that said, your use-case doesn't really lend itself to loops. If your array only contains a single set of `Location` properties, you probably want:

```
if let zipCode = Data[0] as Double,
   let nameCity = Data[1] as? String,
   let gpsLat = Data[2] as? Double,
   let gpsLong = Data[3] as? Double {

    let location = Location(zipCode: zipCode,
        nameCity: nameCity,
        gpsLat: gpsLat,
        gpsLong: gpsLong)
    // Do something with the location we just created
}
```

(BTW, a `Double` is a bad way to store zipcodes. I would suggest using Ints or Strings. Ints work well unless you have a zip code with a leading zero, in which case the leading zero would be truncated.)